# BUG in the r xts package's to.period function?

Tags: r, xts

I inherited some R code that analyses simulation results.  At one point, that code calls the xts package's `to.monthly` function with `indexAt = 'yearmon'` to summarize some values in a zoo.

That code normally runs without issue.  Recently, however, when analysing simulations over much older data, the call to `to.monthly` generated some disturbing Warning messages like this:

```
Warning in zoo(xx, order.by = index(x), ...) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
```

I culled my data down to the minimum size that still exhibits this Warning.  Start with this R code:

```
library(xts)

z = structure(c(-1062503.35419463, -1080996.55425821, -1099783.92018741, 
-1122831.06978888, -1138804.79976585, -1158620.33101501, -1163717.44859603, 
-1183250.17288897, -1212428.97863421, -1234981.23171341, -1253605.89670471, 
-1269885.84780747, -1272023.98376509, -1284471.17954946, -1313114.61914572, 
-1334861.551294, -1349971.87378146, -1360596.77251109, -1363047.71977556, 
-1383840.30131117, -1407963.97518998, -1427010.7195352, -1451908.36211767, 
-1464563.94519573, -1470017.67402451, -1503642.02732151, -1529231.67395429, 
-1560593.79655716, -1582052.24505653, -1595391.99583389), index = structure(c(1111985820, 
1112072340, 1112158740, 1112245140, 1112331540, 1112392740, 1112587140, 
1112673540, 1112759880, 1112846340, 1112932200, 1112993940, 1113191940, 
1113278340, 1113364560, 1113451080, 1113537540, 1113598740, 1113796560, 
1113883140, 1113969540, 1114055940, 1114142220, 1114203540, 1114401480, 
1114487940, 1114574280, 1114660740, 1114747080, 1114808340), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = "zoo")

class(z)
head(z)
tail(z)
```

Then execute this call to `to.monthly`:

```
to.monthly(z, indexAt = 'yearmon', name = "Monthly")
```

On my machine that generates this output:

```
Warning in zoo(xx, order.by = index(x), ...) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
Warning in zoo(xx, order.by = index(x), ...) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
         Monthly.Open Monthly.High Monthly.Low Monthly.Close
Apr 2005     -1062503     -1062503    -1138805      -1138805
Apr 2005     -1158620     -1158620    -1595392      -1595392
```

Note the Warning messages, followed by the result of `to.monthly`, which is a zoo that has the duplicate position of `"Apr 2005"`.

I spent some time executing the code in `to.monthly` line by line, and determined that the bug actually happens inside `to.monthly`'s call to `to.period`.

In particular, I found that the `xx` local variable inside `to.period` is initially calculated correctly, but after the line

```
indexClass(xx) <- indexAt
```

is executed that is when the positions of `xx` become non-unique.

That behavior sure looks like a bug in the xts package's `to.period` function to me.

I would love to hear from someone who knows how `to.monthly/to.period/yearmon` really works either confirm that this is a bug, or explain to me why it is not and give me a work around.

I found [this possibly related report](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/158) on the xts github page (which I do not fully understand).

Concerning my machine:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

...   

other attached packages:
...
xts_0.10-0
zoo_1.8-0
```

When I startup Rgui, I see this Warning message about xts:

```
Warning: package ‘xts’ was built under R version 3.4.2
```

Comment: I get no warnings. In fact I get precisely what I expect, mar and apr 2005 open/high/low/close. `R 3.5.0, xts_0.10-2, zoo_1.8-1`

Comment: @AkselA: what R and xts versions are you using?

Comment: @AkselA: sorry if I missed your version info in your original response.  On my home machine tonight, I completely uninstalled my previous R (3.4.3) and installed the latest R (3.5.1). I then installed the zoo and xts packages.  (Note: had to use the 0-Cloud [https] CRAN mirror, as the other 2 mirrors I first tried lacked them...).  Still no joy: I get the same Warning messages followed by a zoo which has "Apr 2005" appear twice.  My home machine is running Windows 7.  Are you running linux or Mac?

Comment: I'm on a Mac (10.11.6). Have you done much debugging in R before? [Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html) has a nice write-up of handy techniques in case you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug, unrelated to #158.  The problem is that the index of `z` is `POSIXct` in your local timezone.  You aggregate to monthly, which doesn't have a timezone (so xts sets the timezone attribute to `"UTC"`).

But the change in timezone occurs on the `POSIXct` index, which changes the local time before the index is converted to `"yearmon"`.  So, depending on your local timezone's offset from UTC, this may convert the first (last) observation in a month into the last (first) observation of the prior (next) month.

To illustrate:

```
Sys.setenv(TZ = "America/Chicago")
debugonce(xts:::`indexClass<-.xts`)
to.monthly(z, indexAt="yearmon", name="monthly")
# <snip>
# Browse[2]> 
# debug: attr(attr(x, "index"), "tzone") <- "UTC"
# Browse[2]> print(x)  # When timezone is "America/Chicago"
#                     monthly.Open monthly.High monthly.Low monthly.Close
# 2005-03-31 22:59:00     -1062503     -1062503    -1138805      -1138805
# 2005-04-29 15:59:00     -1158620     -1158620    -1595392      -1595392
# Browse[2]> 
# debug: attr(attr(x, "index"), "tclass") <- value
# Browse[2]> print(x)  # When timezone is "UTC"
#                     monthly.Open monthly.High monthly.Low monthly.Close
# 2005-04-01 04:59:00     -1062503     -1062503    -1138805      -1138805
# 2005-04-29 20:59:00     -1158620     -1158620    -1595392      -1595392
# Warning message:
# timezone of object (UTC) is different than current timezone ().
```

You can see that the call to `attr(attr(x, "index"), "tzone") <- "UTC"` pushed the last observation in March into the first day of April (note that the debugger lists the *next* call it will evaluate above my calls to `print(x)`).

Thanks for narrowing it down to the `indexClass<-` call. That made it a lot easier for me to debug!

Comment: I was hoping that you would notice this post!  Thanks for fully figuring it out.  I guess AkselA got the code to run fine, not because he was on a Mac, but because his local timezone was such that he had no pushover into the next month?  Also, any idea when the fix will get pushed into a release?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, AskelA is probably ahead of UTC whereas you and I are behind UTC.  I'm not sure when this will get pushed, because it was also broken in the prior release (0.10-2) and I'm working on things that broke in the release to (0.11-0).  You can probably work-around the issue by specifying the index datetimes as UTC when you import them.

Comment: This looks like another case of [#53](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/53).

Comment: Joshua: concerning your comment *"You can probably work-around the issue by specifying the index datetimes as UTC when you import them"*.  I tired converting the positions of my zoo to have the time zone of UTC using `time = positions(z) ; attr(time, "tzone") = "UTC" ; positions(z) = time`  I found that doing this does cause `to.monthly` to no longer print those warnings.  My only concern is that now the monthly computations will be done using UTC's concept of  month breaks, correct?  This is a slight error in my case, but it could be bad for someone else trying this workaround, right?

Comment: Your concern is valid. I spent some time looking at this and #53 and the solution isn't clear to me due to some of the current complications around how timezones are handled.  I have some refactoring planned that should make it easier to attempt this fix, so I will revisit it after the refactoring is done.